# Websocket - Why can't I send messages to a specific user?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

**Question:**

Why am I being able to send messages to all users but not to a specific user? Am I missing something obvious here?

**Problem:**

My POC uses the following resources:

- The official [Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) for sending messages to all users
- This [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-websockets-send-message-to-user) for sending messages to specific users

I am currently using two endpoints:
The first one sends messages to all users and works fine.

**Send to all users - working**

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public StompResponse greeting(StompRequest message) throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
    return new StompResponse("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
}
```

The second one doesn't work. The method `sendSpecific` never gets called and I'm stuck trying to understand why.

**Send to specific user - NOT working**

```
/**
 * Example of sending message to specific user using 'convertAndSendToUser()' and '/queue'
 */
@MessageMapping(Constants.SECURED_CHAT_ROOM)
public void sendSpecific(@Payload StompRequest message, Principal user, @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("METHOD CALLED"); // This method never gets called
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
    headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

    StompResponse out = new StompResponse(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()));
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("hardcoded_username", Constants.SECURED_CHAT_SPECIFIC_USER, out, headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
}
```

**Socket configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", Constants.SECURED_CHAT_SPECIFIC_USER);
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/secured/user");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/connection-uri").withSockJS();
        registry.addEndpoint(SECURED_CHAT_ROOM).withSockJS();
    }

}
```

**Client code:**

```
const SocketConnection = function(l) {

    const listener = l;
    let sessionId;

    const parseSessionId = (url) => {
        console.log(stompClient.ws._transport.url);
        url = url.replace("ws://localhost:8080" + Uri.CONNECTION_URI + "/",  "");
        url = url.replace("/websocket", "");
        url = url.replace(/^[0-9]+\//, "");
        console.log("Your current session is: " + url);
        return url;
    };

    this.connect = () => {
        const socket = new SockJS(Uri.CONNECTION_URI);
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
            listener.onSocketConnect(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe(Uri.ALL_USERS, function (greeting) {
                listener.onResponseReceived(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
            });

            // WIP
            const url = stompClient.ws._transport.url
            sessionId = parseSessionId(url);

            console.log('SUBSCRIBING FOR SPECIFIC USER: ', Uri.SECURED_CHAT_SPECIFIC_USER)

            // stompClient.subscribe(Uri.SECURED_CHAT_SPECIFIC_USER + sessionId, function (msgOut) {
            stompClient.subscribe(Uri.SECURED_CHAT_SPECIFIC_USER + "-user" + sessionId, function (msgOut) {
                // that.messageOut(JSON.parse(msgOut.body), opts);
                console.log('SINGLE USER WORKS!!!!!!!',JSON.parse(msgOut.body))
            });

        });
    }

    this.disconnect = () => {
        if (stompClient !== null) {
            stompClient.disconnect();
        }
        listener.onSocketConnect(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }

    this.sendRequest = (uri) => {
        stompClient.send(uri, {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
    }

};
```

**Client initialization:**

```
$(function () {
    const socketClient = new SocketConnection(new FormUI());
    $("form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $( "#connect" ).click(function() { socketClient.connect(); });
    $( "#disconnect" ).click(function() { socketClient.disconnect(); });
    $( "#send" ).click(function() {
        socketClient.sendRequest(Uri.ALL_USERS);
        socketClient.sendRequest(Uri.SECURED_CHAT_ROOM);
    });
});
```